# java FXML gridpane is null ! Why?

Tags: java, fxml

I start Java FX and I don't understand why my gridpane is null
and cause me a java.lang.NullPointerException
(at the `grido.add(tf1,2,2);` line)

I have made a lot of change without any result.

Thanks for your help.

**keepSpaceFXML.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<GridPane id="fx:grido" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <Button GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0" text="coucou2" onAction="#handleButtonAction" fx:id="button" />
</GridPane>
```

.

**KeepSpaceFXML.java**

```
package keepspacefxml;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

public class KeepSpaceFXML extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("keepSpaceFXML.fxml"));
        KeepSpaceGridController gridController = new KeepSpaceGridController();
        loader.setController(gridController);
        Parent root = loader.load();
        System.err.println("gridController");
        System.err.println(gridController);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);


        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        gridController.addRow("hello gridpane !");
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

.

**KeepSpaceGridController.java**

```
package keepspacefxml;

import java.net.URL;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

public class KeepSpaceGridController {

    @FXML public GridPane grido;

    @FXML private Label label;

    public void addRow(String text) {
    System.out.println("add row");
    TextField tf1 = new TextField("tf 1");
        System.err.println("grido");
        System.err.println(grido);
    grido.add(tf1,2,2);

    }

    public void setLabel(String text) {
        label.setText(text);
    }


    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("clicked !");
    }

}
```

output is :

```
ant -f /home/doom/Documents/javafxtests/keepSpaceFXML jfxsa-run
init:
Deleting: /home/doom/Documents/javafxtests/keepSpaceFXML/build/built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: /home/doom/Documents/javafxtests/keepSpaceFXML/build/built-jar.properties
Compiling 1 source file to /home/doom/Documents/javafxtests/keepSpaceFXML/build/classes
compile:
Detected JavaFX Ant API version 1.3
Launching <fx:jar> task from /home/doom/jdk1.8.0_141/jre/../lib/ant-javafx.jar
Warning: From JDK7u25 the Codebase manifest attribute should be used to restrict JAR repurposing.
         Please set manifest.custom.codebase property to override the current default non-secure value '*'.
Launching <fx:deploy> task from /home/doom/jdk1.8.0_141/jre/../lib/ant-javafx.jar
No base JDK. Package will use system JRE.
No base JDK. Package will use system JRE.
jfx-deployment-script:
jfx-deployment:
jar:
Copying 12 files to /home/doom/Documents/javafxtests/keepSpaceFXML/dist/run2075630249
jfx-project-run:
Executing /home/doom/Documents/javafxtests/keepSpaceFXML/dist/run2075630249/keepSpaceFXML.jar using platform /home/doom/jdk1.8.0_141/jre/bin/java
gridController
keepspacefxml.KeepSpaceGridController@35d79ed8
add row
grido
null
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at keepspacefxml.KeepSpaceGridController.addRow(KeepSpaceGridController.java:51)
    at keepspacefxml.KeepSpaceFXML.start(KeepSpaceFXML.java:38)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$49(GtkApplication.java:139)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application keepspacefxml.KeepSpaceFXML
Java Result: 1
Deleting directory /home/doom/Documents/javafxtests/keepSpaceFXML/dist/run2075630249
jfxsa-run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: It should be `fx:id="grido"` rather than `id="fx:grido"`.

Comment: It was this ! Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Just FWIW I got here by Googling for why GridPane `getHeight` is null -- turns out the `height` attribute is null if unset! Might help someone, but irrelevant to this case.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know exactly what you want to do but firstly your controller needs implement **Initializable** interface ,and implements initialize method.

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

public class KeepSpaceGridController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    public GridPane grido;

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        addRow("add row");
    }

    public void addRow(String text) {
        System.out.println("add row");
        TextField tf1 = new TextField("tf 1");
        grido.add(tf1, 2, 2);

    }

    public void setLabel(String text) {
        label.setText(text);
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("clicked !");
    }

}
```

Comment: It is by no means necessary to implement `Initializable`.

Comment: In a few words: The method is called first, then any **@FXML** annotated fields are populated,. So this method **addRow** does NOT have access to **@FXML fields** referring to components defined in the .fxml file, while initialize() does have access to them.

Comment: The method `initialize` is indeed called after all `@FXML` annotated fields have been injected, but its existence is not necessary for them to be injected. Having been injected, they are accessible by any method of the controller class.  
In the case of the original question, the call to `addRow` occurs after the call to `FXMLLoader#load` returns, so it is guaranteed to execute after `@FXML` injections.

Comment: Thanks for your work, but the problem is elsewhere. Sillyfly has found the syntax error.